# perl regex: how to escape backslash character

Tags: regex, perl

In the script below I use a replacement pattern that is stored in a variable.
I seem to be unable to get one backslash in my end result. I get either none or two.
It has something to do with the eval statement
Can anybody give me insight on this please.

test.pl:

```
use Data::Dumper;

@arr = ("a", "b", "c");
$re = '$1 \|';
@arr = map { $_ =~ s/($_)/eval qq{"$re"}/e && $_ } @arr;
print Dumper(\@arr);

@arr = ("a", "b", "c");
$re = '$1 \\|';
@arr = map { $_ =~ s/($_)/eval qq{"$re"}/e && $_ } @arr;
print Dumper(\@arr);

@arr = ("a", "b", "c");
$re = '$1 \\\|';
@arr = map { $_ =~ s/($_)/eval qq{"$re"}/e && $_ } @arr;
print Dumper(\@arr);
```

$ test.pl

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a |',
          'b |',
          'c |'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'a |',
          'b |',
          'c |'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'a \\|',
          'b \\|',
          'c \\|'
        ];
```

Answer (score 6):

Data Dumper shows the output in a way to be parsable back by Perl. Two backslashes in single quotes really mean one backslash:

```
print '\\'; # Output: \
```

For reference, [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)

> A single-quoted, literal string.  A backslash represents a
>              backslash unless followed by the delimiter or another backslash, in
>              which case the delimiter or backslash is interpolated.